# Не удалось установить дистрибутив Gradle в android

Tags: java, android, библиотеки, поиск-библиотек, distribution

При загрузке проекта возникла следующая ситуация:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Я нажал на ссылку и скачал то, что требовалось, но куда это теперь нужно добавить, я не знаю

Comment: Вы какой-то старый проект открываете? Версия гредла 2.10 уже очень древняя. Где живёт гредл зависит от типа ОС и настроек АС (`File | Settings | Build, Execution, Deployment | Build Tools | Gradle`). По умолчанию в проекте используется враппер и он складывает дистрибутивы в `~/.gradle/wrapper/dists`, но делается это через одно место, так что если вы там не найдёте папку с именем скачанного дистрибутива, то сами её создать не сможете - он тупо её не увидит. Думаю стоит посмотреть лог (`Help | Show log`), выяснить почему оно само не скачало и исправить. Возможно стоит сразу поднять версию.

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте удалить папки `C:\Users\{your_name}\.gradle` и все что в этих папках:

1. caches
2. daemon
3. wrapper

[вот тут подобный вопрос на enSO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27467155/could-not-install-gradle-distribution-from-https-services-gradle-org-distribu)